# How enable Azure hosted web app to receive API calls from everywhere/wanted source?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I've developed a minimal .NET 6 API. It works fine if I run it locally from Visual Studio (If I make any API call to the endpoints it works).
I've published it to Azure and haven't done any configuration.
The static pages work here as well, but when I try to send a post to my wanted endpoint I get 500 Internal Server Error and from Azure I have this error:
[Azure Application Even Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16anH.png)

Do you have an idea on how I can fix this ?
All the best!

Comment: You're calling a host that does not exist. Use a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had this. What helped me was going into the advanced tools (of the azure portal) of your app service (api). There you can start the KUDU tools.
Go to the debug console CMD - There you can find the folder LogFiles, with inside it the eventlog.xml, which will give you details about the error.
[Kudu tools in Azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hd55.png)